# Getting BeautifulSoup to find a specific <p>

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-content-extraction

I'm trying to put together a basic HTML scraper for a variety of scientific journal websites, specifically trying to get the abstract or introductory paragraph.

The current journal I'm working on is Nature, and the article I've been using as my sample can be seen at http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v463/n7284/abs/nature08715.html.

I can't get the abstract out of that page, however.  I'm searching for everything between the `<p class="lead">...</p>` tags, but I can't seem to figure out how to isolate them.  I thought it would be something simple like

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import re
import urllib2

address="http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v463/n7284/full/nature08715.html"
html = urllib2.urlopen(address).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

abstract = soup.find('p', attrs={'class' : 'lead'})
print abstract
```

Using Python 2.5, BeautifulSoup 3.0.8, running this returns 'None'.  I have no option of using anything else that needs to be compiled/installed (like lxml).  Is BeautifulSoup confused, or am I?

Comment: That's a nasty piece of HTML that site has got...

Comment: Yeah, that is what I am afraid of.  Looking at the prettify() output does not look very pretty towards the middle parts that I am interested in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That html is pretty much malformed, and xml.dom.minidom cannot parse, and BeautiFulSoup parsing not working well.

I removed some `<!-- ... -->` parts and parse again with BeautiFulSoup, then its seems better and able to run `soup.find('p', attrs={'class' : 'lead'})`

Here's the code I tried

```
>>> html =re.sub(re.compile("<!--.*?-->",re.DOTALL),"",html)
>>>
>>> soup=BeautifulSoup(html)
>>>
>>> soup.find('p', attrs={'class' : 'lead'})
<p class="lead">The class of exotic Jupiter-mass planets that orb  .....
```

Comment: That seems to do it for me as well.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

here's a non BS way to get the abstract.

```
address="http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v463/n7284/full/nature08715.html"
html = urllib2.urlopen(address).read()
for para in html.split("</p>"):
    if '<p class="lead">' in para:
        abstract=para.split('<p class="lead">')[1:][0]
        print ' '.join(abstract.split("\n"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the non BS solution, I might need to fall back on this in case of some really ugly pages!

Answer (score 0):

```
  to_p_tag = soup.findAll('p', class_='lead')

  if(len(to_p_tag) == 0):
    print("<p class='lead' /> not found")
  else:
    for p in to_p_tag:
      recursively_translate(translator, p, input_lang)
    # translated_p = translator.translate(to_p_tag.text, dest=input_lang)
    # lxml1 = lxml1.replace(to_p_tag.text,translated_p.text)
```